# Build Output: Consider app.config remapping of assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, compilação

Estou recebendo a mensagem abaixo referente a vários *Assemblies*, o projeto compila e executa normalmente, porém, queria saber como resolver e se pode causar problemas futuros.

> Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Primitives,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version
>   "3.9.0.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll]
>   to solve conflict and get rid of warning.

Comment: Não sei mas isso pode te ajudar: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Vou ler com calma para ver se resolve este problema, obrigado.

Comment: É uma pergunta antiga mas devo perguntar, já conseguiu retirar esses avisos?

Comment: Só sumiram depois que o componente foi atualizado. Não descobri a causa nem como solucionar de outra forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa seção fica no `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      ...
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Primitives" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      ...
    </assemblyBinding>
    ...
  </runtime>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Basicamente, você indica um intervalo de versões em `oldVersion` e o *assembly* mais recente em `newVersion`. Não tem muito segredo.

O compilador dá este aviso quando a versão do *assembly* foi encontrada, mas que isso pode não acontecer sempre. A configuração acima resolve este problema.

Comment: Obrigado, no meu caso `app.config`, teve situações que tive que adicionar pois a configuração nem existia.

Comment: Voltaram as mensagens, não vou mais bater cabeça, vou conviver com elas. :).

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Este sistema é o que, exatamente?

Comment: Uma aplicação `Xamarin Forms` @cigano-morrison-mendez